# How to add navbar tabs in Foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop, foreach, tabs

This is the code for displaying tabs but already I display but when i
click on tabs it doesn't show anything because its in the foreach loop so
there is only one li. so what should i do. pls help.

```
<div class="commerce-tabs">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs">
        <?php foreach($Addons as $newAddons){ ?>
        <li class="active">
            <a data-toggle="tab" href="#tab-noo_boxes_tab<?php echo $itm_id;?>">
                <?php echo $newAddons->cat_name; ?></a>
        </li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" style="background-color: #fff;">
        <?php foreach($newAddons->Items as $newnewAddons){?>
        <input type="hidden" name="addons_item_name[]" value="<?php echo $newnewAddons->item_name;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="itm_ids[]" value="<?php echo $newnewAddons->itm_id;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="uom_id[]" value="<?php echo $newnewAddons->uom_id;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="sh_price[]" value="<?php echo $newnewAddons->sh_price;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="totalAmt[]" value="<?php echo $newnewAddons->totalAmt;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="total_net_amt[]" value="<?php echo $newnewAddons->total_net_amt;?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="adonprice[]" value="<?php echo $newnewAddons->price;?>">
        <div class="content2">
            <br>
            <div class="wrap row">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="tab-noo_boxes_tab" style="background-color: #fff;">
                    <div class="col-md-4">
                        <?php echo $newnewAddons->item_name;?></div>
                    <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: center;">
                        <button type="button" id="sub" class="sub single_add_to_cart_button button">-</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-4" style="text-align: center;">
                        <input class="count form-control" type="text" id="1" name="itm_weight[]" value="0" min="0" max="100" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-2" style="text-align: center;">
                        <button type="button" id="add" class="add single_add_to_cart_button button">+</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can i dynamically generate different bootstrap tabs with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45393051/how-can-i-dynamically-generate-different-bootstrap-tabs-with-php)

Comment: Unrelated: having `class="active"` on _every_ tab makes little sense

Comment: Run `foreach($Addons as $newAddons) ...` again for all of your tabs content